# "Injecting the input artifact of a transform as a File has been deprecated."

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the warning `"Injecting the input artifact of a transform as a File has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Declare the input artifact as a Provider<FileSystemLocation> instead."` when Syncing my Gradle.

What in the world does that mean?

I see in the stack trace for the warning something about `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ExtractAarTransform`. I do have two dependencies using `@aar` in my build.gradle:

`implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.8@aar') { transitive = true }`

and

`implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.16.8@aar'`

Could it be one of these that the warning is referring to? What am I supposed to do with these if not whatever I am doing with them already?

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

**Based** On https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

Starting from version 1.3.30, kapt supports incremental annotation processing as an experimental feature. Currently, annotation processing can be incremental only if all annotation processors being used are incremental.

Incremental annotation processing is enabled by default starting from version 1.3.50. To disable incremental annotation processing, add this line to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
kapt.incremental.apt=false
```

**Incremental compilation**
The Kotlin Gradle plugin supports incremental compilation. Incremental compilation tracks changes of source files between builds so only files affected by these changes would be compiled.